# PHP - span closing tag in with Ternary Operator

Tags: php, tags, conditional-operator

```
$json = '[{"Number":"333567","Cost":0},{"Number":"333568","Cost":7500},{"Number":"333569","Cost":7500}]';
    $options = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        $newArray[$value['Number']]= $value['Number']." "."<br /> <span>".($value['Cost'] / 100 == 0 ? 'Free </span>': "&pound; </span>".$value['Cost'] / 100);
    }
   echo '<br>';
   echo '<br>';
   echo json_encode($newArray);
   echo '<br>';
```

I need to add span tag only around **Cost** Free and with price not with **Number**

Closing tag is wont be rendered...

I tried many things but stuck on this:

```
$newArray[$value['Number']]= $value['Number']." "."<br /> <span>".($value['Cost'] / 100 == 0 ? 'Free' : "&pound;".($value['Cost'] / 100)."</span>");
```

Comment: In your attempt, it should be `</span>` at the end instead of `<span>`

Comment: Sry my typo, it is </span> after that it results `"333568
£75<\/span>"`

Comment: Why is this tagged with `regex`? Sometimes using an `if` clause is "easier" than using ternary. If you need to use it, add a `</span>` after `Free` and move your last `</span>` after `&pound;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newArray[$value['Number']]= $value['Number']." "."<br /> <span>".($value['Cost'] / 100 == 0 ? 'Free' : "&pound;".($value['Cost'] / 100))."</span>";
```

Comment: Results are still problematic with closing tags: `{"333567":"333567
Free<\/span>","333568":"333568
£75<\/span>","333569":"333569
£75<\/span>"}`

Comment: Somehow didn't work on testing env but on module works fine, thanks!!!